# Why is this shorthand ternary operator throwing an error?

Tags: php, associative-array, conditional-operator

I have this code in a method:

```
$remainder_payment = $this->product_info['remainder_payment'] ?: 0;
```

And I am getting this error:

> Undefined index: remainder_payment in...

In my mind I am setting $remainder_payment to $this->product_info['remainder_payment'] if $this->product_info['remainder_payment'] is not false, otherwise $remainder_payment = 0.

[Looking at this table in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) if an item in undefined then it should evaluate to false, but instead I'm getting an error.

Comment: I think you're looking for the null coalescing operator `??`

Comment: @arkascha He's using the shorthand ternary that uses the condition as the true value.

Comment: As suggested above: This should work `$this->product_info['remainder_payment'] ?? 0`

Comment: Elvis operator does raise a notice or warning if the index doesn't exist. It is the null coalescing one that doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the ternary operator is essentially an if statement, and like an if statement it will throw the warning if you try to access the array key without it existing.

What you want is the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) `??`

`$remainder_payment = $this->product_info['remainder_payment'] ?? 0;`